# Listing keys containing a given string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

**Given data** such as :

```
var people = [ 
    { 'myKey': 'John Kenedy', 'status': 1 },
    { 'myKey': 'Steeven Red', 'status': 0 },
    { 'myKey': 'Mary_Kenedy', 'status': 3 },
    { 'myKey': 'Carl Orange', 'status': 0 },
    { 'myKey': 'Lady Purple', 'status': 0 },
    ...                                       // thousands more
];
```

**How to efficiently get the list of all objects which contains in `myKey` the string `Kenedy` ?**

http://jsfiddle.net/yb3rdhm8/

---

**Note:** I currently use `str.search()` :

> The search("str") returns the position of the match. Returns -1 if no match is found.

to do as follow :

```
var map_partial_matches = function(object, str){
    var list_of_people_with_kenedy = [] ;
    for (var j in object) {
        if (object[j]["myKey"].search(str) != -1) { 
            object[j].presidentName = "yes";  // do something to object[j]
            list_of_people_with_kenedy.push({ "people": object[j]["myKey"] }); // add object key to new list  
        }
    } return list_of_people_with_kenedy;
}
map_partial_matches(people, "Kenedy");
```

I could do the same using `str.match()` :

> `str.match()` returns the matches, as an Array object. Returns `null` if no match is found.

It works anyway, but I have no idea if it's efficient or completely dump.

Comment: That's not JSON. It's a javascript array of object literals.

Comment: Just a side note: If you want to use a lib, linq.js is pretty good and fast! http://linqjs.codeplex.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a basic function that uses [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return an array of matches based on a key and value:

```
function find(arr, key, val) {
  return arr.filter(function (el) {
    return el[key].indexOf(val) > -1;
  });
}

var result = find(people, 'myKey', 'Kenedy');
```

Alternatively use a normal `for...loop`:

```
function find(arr, key, val) {
  var out = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (arr[i][key].indexOf(val) > -1) {
      out.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/w10gd5qp/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter()`:

```
var filtered = people.filter(function (item) {

    if (item.myKey.indexOf("Kenedy") != -1) 
       return item;

});
```

You can also checkout [**Sugar.js**](http://sugarjs.com/)

Comment: Note that the OP is not just searching, but also adding a property to the matching items. Also, using `filter` is more concise, but it can't do any better than `o(n)`

Comment: Filtering is still interesting since I may also first list my targets, then apply some changes.

Answer (score 2):

In order to search your unsorted object you need to get through all of it's properties - So I'd say a simple loop with an `indexOf` will be pretty much the best you can go:

```
var foundItems = [];
for(var i = 0; i < people.length ;i++)
{
    if(people[i].myKey.indexOf('Kenedy') > -1)
       foundItems.push(people[i]]);       
}
```

Maybe you can tweak it up a little, but it's pretty much the best you can get.

Comment: You should really use a more suitable loop since it's an array, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
Does the Object Contain a Given Key?
function hKey(obj, key) {
    arr = [];
   // newarr =[];
    for(el in obj){
      arr.push(el)
    } //return arr;
    for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
         name = arr[i]
    }   if(name == key) {
           return true;
       }else {
           return false;
       }
}
console.log(hKey({ a: 44, b: 45, c: 46 }, "c"))
```